# Content assist cannot find proposals in "loop" if there is code below

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, content-assist

I had some problems with content assist this morning and decided to update eclipse. Unfortunately, that did not fix the issue, but I eventually managed to fix it. After some time though, another issue arose and I decided to completely reinstall eclipse this time, but to no avail.

Now, whenever I'm in a loop (doesn't matter which), I cannot use content assist if more code follows below. Let me give you an example.

If I use ctrl-space after this sysout, it will work,

```
while (true) {
    sysout
}
```

but if I use ctrl-space for this sysout, it will tell me that no proposals were found.

```
while (true) {
    sysout
    (Some code) //Can be a sysout, a mathematical expression or pretty much anything else. It will only work if the following code is another loop, an if statement or a variable declaration.
}
```

I've even used another workspace on this clean version of eclipse and it still doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: The same issue appears in an if statement as well. It looks like anything that has a condition breaks my content assist

Comment: What version of eclipse are you using?  It works fine for me with 2019-06 (4.12.0)

Comment: I'm using the 2021-06. I've just downloaded it from their website.

Comment: I sometimes see this if there are errors in the 'some code', otherwise it works.

Comment: It unfortunately doesn't change anything if there are errors or not.

Comment: I have 2021-06 too but couldn't reproduce the issue. May be there's something specific to the code after the sysout. Try to add info to your question so it's a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It only works if the code following the sysout is a variable declaration or the start of an other loop or if statment. If there is sysout, a mathematical expression or anything else, it stops working.

Comment: Unable to reproduce it here with 2021-06.  However, much may depend on **where the cursor is exactly when pressing ctrl-space.**  I've been placing the cursor right after the sysout on the same line.  It offers 2 suggestions, first is useless does nothing, second says `sysout - print to standard out`.   Placing it inside the sysout characters prompts even more suggestions.  *Where is your cursor?*  Do you see the second suggestion about standard out?

Comment: @Bouch Do you get "no proposals" or "sysout - print to standard out"?

Comment: Wherever I put my cursor, it says: "no proposal found". https://imgur.com/a/AGeHxvq

Comment: And even though the line under has no mistakes, it tells me this:
Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token ".", ; 
  expected
 - out cannot be resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is indeed an **issue of Eclipse 2021-06 (4.20)** that happens inside conditions and loops when there is trailing code not separated by a semicolon `;` ([similar but not the same as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68258236/6505250)).

Example:

```
class Sample {
    void sample(String foo) {
        if (foo != null) {
            sys // content assist here
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

I created the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) above and reported it here for you:

[**Eclipse bug 574267** - [content assist] [regression] No content assist for templates in conditional blocks](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=574267#c2)

As workaround you can add a `;` after the location where to use the content assist.

**Update:**

After less than 4 hours after [reporting a reproducible example](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=574267#c2), the [**issue has been fixed**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=574267#c6). So, as an alternative to the above mentioned workaround, you can wait for the upcoming release **Eclipse 2021-09 (4.21)** on September 15, 2021 or at least for the first milestone build of it on July 16, 2021.

Comment: Oh wow! sorry for the excessively late reply, but thank you so very much!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68265945/6167720)?

(would have added comment, but too little rep)

Comment: Similar but not the same and not yet fixed. See my answer.

Comment: Now, it has also been fixed. See my updated answer.